# Nasm simple bootloader. Call and ret do not work properly

Tags: assembly, system, nasm, bootloader

I have this code:

```
;bootloader
[bits 16]
[org 0x7c00]

jmp main

print_char:
    mov ah,0x0e
    mov bh,0x00
    mov al,65
    int 0x10
ret

main:
    call print_char

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

So, it should jump to main and call print_char to print a letter A on the screen, but it doesn't work! I'am using a qemu+gdb for testing. I set sevreal breakpoints in gdb one at the begining, anouther one at call print_char and last one on ret. I found that print_char is not called in this code. What is wrong with my code?

My debug session:

```
(gdb) target remote localhost:1234
Remote debugging using localhost:1234
0x0000fff0 in ?? ()
(gdb) br *0x7c00
Breakpoint 1 at 0x7c00
(gdb) br *0x7c00+0x3
Breakpoint 2 at 0x7c03
(gdb) br *0x7c00+0xb
Breakpoint 3 at 0x7c0b
(gdb) br *0x7c00+0xc
Breakpoint 4 at 0x7c0c
(gdb) stepi
0x0000e05b in ?? ()
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, 0x00007c00 in ?? ()
(gdb) stepi

Breakpoint 4, 0x00007c0c in ?? ()
(gdb) stepi
0x00007c0e in ?? ()
(gdb) stepi
0x00007c10 in ?? ()
(gdb) stepi
0x00007c12 in ?? ()
(gdb) stepi
0x00007c15 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

lst file:

```
 1                                  ;bootloader
 2                                  [bits 16]
 3                                  [org 0x7c00]
 4                                  
 5                                  
 6 00000000 E90900                  jmp main
 7                                  
 8                                  print_char:
 9 00000003 B40E                        mov ah,0x0e
10 00000005 B700                        mov bh,0x00
11 00000007 B041                        mov al,65
12 00000009 CD10                        int 0x10
13 0000000B C3                      ret
14                                  
15                                  main:
16 0000000C E8F4FF                      call print_char
17                                      
18                                  
19 0000000F 00<rept>                times 510-($-$$) db 0
20         
                     
21 000001FE 55AA                    dw 0xAA55
```

---

#### Solved.

It seems to bad floppy image. Fixed with starting qemu with my binary file like`qemu boot.bin`

Comment: The only problem I can see is that you have no code after the `CALL`. Adding a `JMP $` for an endless loop and running in qemu does produce the expected letter `A` on the screen all right. I think you might be seeing `gdb` bug. It's not very good at debugging 16 bit real mode code.

Comment: Adding a jmp $ after call print_char doesn't change anything. Gdb just ignoring it.

Comment: But just running it, don't you get the `A` printed? It should work fine, it's just a debugging problem.

Comment: No there is only "Booting from floppy..." and cursor on the new line. That's all. The problem is still in call instruction - it just doesn't work.

Comment: It works fine here, even using `gdb`.

Comment: Dunno, probably some problems with compilation and writing an image?

    nasm -f bin bootloader.asm -o sys/bootloader.bin -l bootloader.lst
    bfi -f=sys.img sys/ -b=bootloader.bin
    qemu-system-x86_64 -fda sys.img -boot a

Sorry, i don't know how set this text as code.

Comment: Not sure what `bfi` is, but I don't think it matters. I just did `qemu-system-x86_64 bootloader.bin`.

Comment: Wow! Now it works as expected! But my image do not work. Any ideas? Or can you explain how to create a bootable image with my bootloader.bin?

Comment: You just booted it, so it is already a bootable image. ;)

Comment: But if i want to write my "os" to a floppy and there will be several files? Anyway thanks a lot for help! Can't add reputation to you it requeres 15 points to be in my carma. :(

Comment: You don't have a filesystem yet. You can append more sectors as you like (but you will have to load them yourself).

Answer (score 0):

Not the actual question, but the one asked in the comments:

> But if i want to write my "os" to a floppy and there will be several files?

Are you:
- On Windows?
Use Virtual Floppy Disk, a free tool. Not sure how it works though.
- On Linux?
Use `dd` and `mkfs.fat`.
`dd if=/dev/zero of=floppy.img bs=512 count=2880` will make a 1.44M floppy for you.
`losetup /dev/loop0 floppy.img` connects the image to a device file.
`mkfs.fat /dev/loop0` will create the FAT12 file system usually used on floppies.
`dd if=bootloader.bin of=floppy.img` installs your bootloader.
- On OS X?
Use `hdiutil`.
`hdiutil create -type UDIF -layout NONE -sectors 2880 -fs "MS-DOS FAT12" floppy.img` creates the formatted floppy image.
`dd if=bootloader.bin of=floppy.img` installs the bootloader. Same as Linux.

You should set up a [BIOS parameter block](http://wiki.osdev.org/FAT), otherwise the image can not be mounted.

Keep the project going!